# Angular 4 - Chamar função do Componente através do service

Tags: javascript, angular

Como Faço, estando no service, para chamar uma função do componente que instanciou este service?

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível fazer isso...

Comment: Não sou especialista em Angular*, mas em AngularJs você pode implementar um mecanismo de registro de *watchers* e publicação. Funciona assim: Seu serviço possui um método, `register()`, onde você passa como parâmetros escopo atual e a função a ser chamada (callback). Do lado do serviço você adiciona os dois a uma coleção de *watchers*. No momento desejado você chama todos os `callbacks` válidos.

Comment: Provavelmente sua aplicação não deveria fazer isso. tem como vc postar o código como exemplo?

Answer (score 2):

No Angular2, os components nao devem ficar com logica de regra de negocio, estas devem ficar nos Services , nos components devem ficar apenas coisas relacionadas ao template da aplicacao, as coisas relacionadas  a maniopulacao de dados devem estar no Service.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode comunicar via `Subject`, no conceito de enviar e receber mensagens.

Por exemplo, seu service vai existir duas funções, uma que recebe e outra que envia.

```
@Injectable()
export class AlgumService{
    private subject = new Subject<string>();

    enviaMensagem(texto: string) {
        this.subject.next(texto);
    }

    recebeMensagem(): Observable<string> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

No seu outro service, voce chama o `AlgumService`:

```
nomeMetodo() {
    // envia mensagem
    this.algumService.enviaMensagem('Seja bem vindo'):
}
```

e no seu `Component` em `OnInit()`, voce recebe ele:

```
this.algumService.recebeMensagem().subscribe(mensagem => {
    console.log(mensagem); // Seja bem vindo
    // chame sua funcao qualquer no componente
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```